# Use rsync with closed files only

Tags: rsync

I am interested in using rsync with the --remove-source-files option. I am planning on pointing it to a directory, with a command like:

```
rsync -avm --remove-source-files --include='*.dat' -f 'hide,! */' . /destination_dir
```

If I have a file open for writing in the directory, will rsync be smart enough to not transfer that file until it is closed?

Comment: No, and a program may never stop running and close it's files.The answer to this is snapshots. LVM and ZFS are options, depending on your OS.

Comment: well it may be acceptable if rsync uses deltas. I was kind of wondering if my scenario might work if I used the whole file flag